# Add the new items display top of position in Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

If I add new Item to wishlist RecyclerView can added only at last row, but i want to display at top of 0th position in RecyclerView.
I tried to display first position of RecyclerView, but Its doesn't workout well.

Code

```
 data.add(new CartitemModel(prodcutname, product_alias, MRPPRICE, SALES, OFFER, imagone, productid));
 wishadapter = new WishlistAdapter(data, wishlist_Items.this);
 recyleitems.setAdapter(wishadapter);
 wishadapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
```

Comment: Post the code where you are adding new data

Comment: updated now let see above

Comment: Do as data.add(0, yourObject);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a list of items. When you want to add another item to the top use

```
  data.add(0,new CartitemModel(prodcutname, product_alias, MRPPRICE, SALES, OFFER, imagone, productid));
  wishadapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
```

This will work as now you are adding the item to top of list.

Comment: did I use  wishadapter.notifydatasetchaged()

Comment: It's added the second position

Comment: Unless you are inverting your recycer Layout manager this wont happen.

Comment: But, I have doubt  if I attached the adapter in volley It may cause null pointer exception

Comment: Why are you creating new adapter after volley completes? Create it before hand with empty data. Then you can just add the new items to data and call wishadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();